# define a method that returns true if the receiving object is larger than the argument object ruby

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I'm a ruby newbie doing a full stack web dev course @ Bloc.io and I'm having trouble with the following...

"We should be able to call a larger_than? method on each shape. This method should evaluate two shapes and return true or false depending on one shape's area being larger than the other. In other words, the larger_than? method should return true if the receiving object is larger than the argument object:

```
square.larger_than?(rectangle)
```

"true if the square is larger than the rectangle, false if not"

These are the specs:

```
describe "Shape" do
  describe "larger_than?" do
    it "should tell if a shape is larger than another shape" do
      class A < Shape
        def area
          5
        end
      end
      class B < Shape
        def area
          10
        end
      end
      a = A.new
      b = B.new
      expect( b.larger_than?(a) ).to eq(true)
      expect( a.larger_than?(b) ).to eq(false)
    end
  end

This is my code:

class Shape
  attr_accessor :color

  def initialize(color = nil)
    @color = color || 'Red'
  end

  def larger_than?
    if Shape.new.area > self.class.area
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end

class Rectangle < Shape
  attr_accessor :width, :height

  def initialize(width, height, color = nil)
    @width, @height = width, height
    super(color) 
  end

  def area
    width * height
  end
end

class Square < Rectangle
  def initialize(side, color = nil)
    super(side, side, color)
  end
end

class Circle < Shape
  attr_accessor :radius

  def initialize(radius, color = nil)
    @radius = radius
    super(color) 
  end

  def area
    Math::PI * (radius * radius)
  end
end
```

The error:

```
ArgumentError
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
exercise.rb:8:in `larger_than?'

exercise_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I would really appreciate some feedback on what I'm missing/doing wrong.

Comment: "is larger than the *argument* object"

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am trying not to give you the solution, but instead hints to get the solution yourself.

---

Your code looks good except for the `larger_than?` method. Think again about how the method is called:

```
square.larger_than?(rectangle)
```

It is called on a `Shape` object, with another `Shape` object as the first parameter.

So, the method expects a parameter (the other shape).
Within the method, you can access the current shape with `self` and the other shape (using the parameter) to compare both areas.

---

One more little thing: You are doing this:

```
if Shape.new.area > self.class.area
  true
else
  false
end
```

The test-expression in your `if` statement already returns a `Boolean` (`true` in the first case and `false` in the second). So you can directly return the value of the test-expression instead of writing that `if` statement.

---

**Update**:

The `larger_than?` method should look similar to this:

```
def larger_than?(otherShape)
  self.area > otherShape.area
end
```

`self` is the Shape where the `larger_than?` method is called on. To compare both shapes, you have to compare the areas of those shapes.

Comment: You can define a method with parameters like this: `def larger_than?(otherShape)` With the `larger_than?` method defined like this, you can access the other shape withing the method body with `otherShape`.

Comment: Hi @MathewLeonWorsley I have edited my answer to give an example of how the solution can look like. You are pretty close to the solution. It's just that you want to compare the `area` and not the shapes themselves. Also, `self` already is a shape (no need for `self.Shape`).

Comment: I see :D Thanks @tessi I'm still having a little trouble getting my head around how classes and subclasses use methods between each other...